# Find PMF for a function of random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $Y = \frac{X}{X + 1}$

where:

- $Y$ and $X$ are random variables,
- $f_X(x)$ is the probability mass function (PMF) of $X$, defined as:
  $ f_X(x) = \frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{N}}$
  where $\mathbb{N}$ represents the set of natural numbers and $\mathbf{1}$ is Euler's indicator function.

Is my approach correct?

We know that the PMF for $X$ is given as
$$ f_X(x) = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x\quad\text{ for } x \in \mathbb{N} $$

Now, we can find the PMF for $Y$ by substituting the values of $X$ into the definition of $Y$:
$$
P_Y(y) = P(Y = y) = P\left(\frac{X}{X + 1} = y\right) = P\left(X = \frac{y}{1 - y}\right).
$$

If $\frac{y}{1 - y}$ is a natural number, then $P_Y(y)$ will be equal to the PMF of $X$ for that corresponding $x$.

$$P_Y(y) = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{\frac{y}{1 - y}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the approach is correct, but it is missing the indicator function that restricts the support of $Y$ accordingly.  You write "if $\frac{y}{1-y}$ is a natural number," how do we more precisely characterize this?

Note that if $Y = \frac{X}{X+1}$ and $X \in \mathbb N$, then the support of $Y$ is the set
$$Y \in \left\{\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{3}{4}, \ldots \right\}.$$
So you could write
$$\Pr[Y = y] = \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{\frac{y}{1-y}} \mathbb 1(y \in \{\tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{2}{3}, \tfrac{3}{4}, \ldots\})$$
which I think is more readily understandable than
$$\Pr[Y = y] = \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{\frac{y}{1-y}} \mathbb 1 \left(\tfrac{y}{1-y} \in \mathbb N\right).$$

Comment: Thank you so much!